# Emploi du verbe "procrastiner" pour rendre l'idée de "remettre aux calendes grecques"

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, histoire, latin, grec

L'expression "remettre aux calendes grecques" est-elle répandue/reconnue ?
Peut-on couramment rendre son sens avec le verbe "procrastiner" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oui! Elle est très usuelle mais forcément pas au sens de *procrastiner* qui signifie plus remettre à plus tard, à demain. On le fera sûrement mais... un autre jour, alors que :

Comme tu le sais mieux que nous... les Grecs n'ayant pas de calendes... *remettre aux calendes grecques* signifie très exactement qu'on ne le fera... ni demain ni un autre jour... mais bien qu'on ne le fera **jamais**.

---

Note que le français connaît aussi dans le genre la *remise sine die*. C'est une certaine forme de procrastination. On le fera certainement un jour mais... juste... on sait pas dire précisément lequel.

---

<sup>NDaCOSwt : Et... parce que ce sujet m'a amusé... finalement... les choses que ne n'admets de faire qu'à titre posthume... c'est de la procrastination ou de la remise aux calendes grecques ?
Bon! Je vous autorise trancher : c'est du foutage de gueule! Mais bon... ce sujet en était-il exempt ?</sup>

Comment: Merci ! Le verbe procrastiner est autant usuel ? Je l'ai appris aujourd'hui quand j'ai voulu expliquer à quelques étudiants "remettre aux calendes grecques" :-)! À propos je ne l'avais jamais entendu...

Comment: @Dimitris : *procrastiner* est **très** usuel... parmi les gens... comme moi.. (mes potes et moi ;-) )qui en font leur spécialité, leur Art! :-) et qui donc... comme moi... déguisent leur flemme sous un mot savant... et donc présumé... non usuel pour les autres... :-)

Comment: @Dimitris : Au fait... juste pour dire... la réponse à mes question en Grec... tu procrastines ou t'as remis aux calendes grecques ? Bon... parce que dans un cas je pardonne évidemment et dans l'autre... je vais t'en vouloir... ;-)

Comment: Le verbe `procrastiner` a beaucoup gagné en popularité ces dernières années. Ou alors c'est moi qui ai vieilli ?

Comment: @Dimitris J'espère que tu as déjà remarqué l'humour de aCOSwt. Mais au cas où... (parce que ce n'est pas toujours facile de le percevoir dans une langue et culture qui ne sont pas siennes au départ) le mot est perçu comme encore très littéraire et son emploi cantonné à une certaine partie de la population (mais on s'attend à ce que tes étudiants comprennent). Le verbe est moins employé que le nom (c'est apparemment le contraire en anglais, je viens de générer quelques Ngrams). J'ai dis « encore » parce que, comme le fait remarquer Destal, il connait un renouveau depuis une vingtaine d'année.

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous : Merci pour ton exégèse... comme d'habitude très juste. Out of interest... suis-je sexiste ou juste réaliste si je dis que **Aucune** femme que je connais ne se refuse à, parfois, remettre aux calendres grecques... mais que... absolument **aucune** (de celles que je connais) ne supporte / tolère (pas plus pour elles-mêmes que pour les autres) la procrastination ?

Comment: Il ne faut jamais remettre au lendemain… *ce que l’on peut faire faire le surlendemain par un autre*, antique sagesse de survie en milieu hostile.

Comment: @cl-r : ++ !!  Quoique... Attends! *... ce que l'on peut raisonnablement espérer qu'autrui, par lassitude, fera de sa propre initiative plus tard!*... ça fait moins dirigiste comme *sagesse*... ;-)

Comment: La Sagesse n’est pas le fruit de la Raison, mais de l’expérience… supposer l’Autre raisonnable, entrant dans son domaine de pensées, amène de fortes déconvenues, et l’Espoir n’est qu’un déguisement de la peur de la Mort, ce qui est rédhibitoire en milieu hostile, quant à lasser un paresseux…

Comment: ***Le sage procrastine*** : il s’assied sur la berge du fleuve et fini par voir passer le corps de son ennemi… et si le corps qui passe n’est pas celui de l’ennemi, il se réjouit pour celui qui a un ennemi en moins… à moins que le passager de l’onde soit un ennemi de son ennemi… À vous de terminer l’histoire :-)